# Why when i use TshadowEffect i have error FlushClientOps: ops pending timeout on some mobile

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Under Android, when i create a control with a TshadowEffect and show it on the top of my form, then on some mobiles (not on all, just on some, like galaxy S4), my form is "freezing" for 2 - 3 seconds, the time i receive in my log the error :

```
E/IMGSRV(6733): :0: FlushClientOps: ops pending timeout
E/IMGSRV(6733): :0: PVRSRVFreeDeviceMem: FlushClientOps failed
```

after i receive theses logs, my form and my control + TshadowEffect are working perfectly well. I have this error only on some some mobile like galaxy S4.

Any idea what going wrong ?

Comment: How about providing some [mcve]

Comment: Dalija, i think an example will be useless because it's happen only on some mobile, so you will not be able to reproduce it. on some other it's work very well. anyway i find a way around to draw myself the shadow and not use the TshadowEffect at all

Comment: If you think providing example is useless, then you shouldn't asked question here. As-is is your question is useless. With example code someone might be able to reproduce it and get to the bottom of it. Without example we cannot even do that.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I ask mostly to know if someone know about FlushClientOps and PVRSRVFreeDeviceMem. I think it's connected to the device driver.

Comment: Maybe someone knows questions are more suitable for [Delphi G+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103113685381486591754) or regular Delphi forums.

Comment: Also absolutely best course of action would be reporting issue to Quality Portal, but again you will need to supply proper MCVE project.